# Monitor status of a command I spawn using Popen

Tags: python

I use Popen() to spawn a program? That program will display 'text' at the program?

How can I monitor status of my program I spawn? How can I determine if there is nothing print out for 1 min, i assume the program is hang and I need to kill the process 'p'?

```
# command is my command to run
p = subprocess.Popen(command,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen

Comment: oops, I meant this one http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects

Comment: provide custom pipes to `stdout=` and `stdout=` and read from it for program output.

Comment: you can monitor status of process by psutil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is largely based on [Non-blocking read on a subprocess.PIPE in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/non-blocking-read-on-a-subprocess-pipe-in-python/4896288#4896288)

We use a separate thread and Queue to check for output after a certain amount of time, given in the `q.get(timeout=5)` portion. Change it to `60` if you only want to kill the process after 60 seconds. Change the first argument to `subprocess.Popen` to an appropriate command you want to run.

```
import Queue
import subprocess
import threading

def checkStdout(p, q):
    s = p.stdout.read(1)
    if len(s) > 0:
        q.put(s)

def run():
    p = subprocess.Popen(['cat'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, close_fds=True)
    print 'pid %d started' % p.pid
    q = Queue.Queue()
    t = threading.Thread(target=checkStdout, args=(p, q))
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    try:
        canGet = q.get(timeout=5)
        print 'has output'
    except Queue.Empty:
        print 'no output'
        # kill process
        p.kill()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Comment: Thanks. I tired this in my script. I see 'has output'. But then the function run just return without waiting for p (the process running my command (replace your 'cat' in your example) to finish.

Comment: Try adding a `p.communicate()` after the `print 'has output'`, I think that will wait for the process to terminate. http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate